# Asp.Net MVC Url.Action gives 404 resource not found error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am running into this error while using Url.Action is ASP.net MVC 5

**Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
Requested URL: /Home/AddPhoto**

Here is the relevant portion of the view. The following url.action call is the one that fails : **@Url.Action("AddPhoto", "Home")**

```
  </div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <textarea class="search-query span2 text-center" rows="13" style="width: 2200px; height: 50px;" id="searchText" name="searchText" placeholder="What is on your mind?" type="text" value="What is on your mind? "></textarea>
                <br />
                <a href="#" id="addphoto" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("AddPhoto", "Home")'">

                    <span rel="tooltip" title="Add photo"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></span>
                </a>
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="reset" value="Cancel" name="Command" style="text-align:right" />&nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="submit" name="Command" value="Post" style="text-align:right" />
                <br />
                <br />
```

In my HomeController.cs file, I do have this method:

```
public ActionResult AddPhoto()
{
   return View();
}
```

And the actual view file , does exist under Views/Home

[Screen grab of views/home directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt7QV.png)

I am hence not understanding the reason why I am hitting the 404 not found error. Can someone please help me out over here?

Comment: When you go to /Home/AddPhoto using the browser URL, is the page served?

Comment: try typing the url in browser location directly and check - http://localhost:portno/home/AddPhoto is it accessible?

Comment: @Ashish Kaluskar, Try this: go to Action , onclick View than select "Go to view",  Than add on top of your action this : [HttpPost]

Comment: Bon and  Karthik ., No it is not. I even tried creating a new view (a empty view without model)  and tried to access it via the browser. still i get the same 404 not found error. The weird part is that I am able to view the Index.cshtml and About.cshtml views, both of which reside in the Views/Home directory. But any view that I create in that directory gives the 404 not found error

Comment: @Ashish Kaluskar, try to add [HttpPost] on top of Action

Comment: when you do inspect element from developer tools are you able to see expected URL for your anchor tag?

Comment: @AshishKaluskar - can you mark it as useful so that other users can easily see the useful votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddPhoto action in your case must be [HttpPost]. It should be [HttpGet]. Remove [HttpPost]. Only GET works from browser location bar.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:
Try this:

```
<a href="#" id="addphoto" onclick="window.location.href='../Home/AddPhoto'">
```

or

```
<a href="~/Home/AddPhoto" id="addphoto">`
```

Hope it helps;)